# Prevent locally stored data to get ereased

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Hive to store data locally, which works fine, but when I clear all data (under Settings) all of the locally stored data is gone. Is there any way in Flutter to store the data in the phone and have it even after the app data was ereased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data gets removed when any app gets unloaded, and this is probably the best for the user, if they're clearing means the app is not a priority for them, and they probably don't want the data either.

That being said, you have two options:

- use external storage (google cloud, AWS, etc)
- persist the data using external storage directories

Consider using:
https://pub.dev/packages/external_path
or: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

This won't work for all the platforms and you'll need special permissions: [Flutter : Create directory on external storage path - path provider getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54379206/2161256)

your code will look something like this:

```dart
Future<Directory> getExternalStorageDirectory() async {
  Directory externalDirectory;
  
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    externalDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    externalDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }

  return externalDirectory;
}

Future<void> saveData(String data) async {
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final file = File('${directory.path}/my_data.txt');
  await file.writeAsString(data);
}

Future<String> readData() async {
  try {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final file = File('${directory.path}/my_data.txt');
    String data = await file.readAsString();
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```